# Is this the main water shutoff valve?

Tags: plumbing, valve

I was looking around for my main water shutoff valve, and I found this hole in the ground (about 2.5' deep and 4" dia.) with a pipe coming out of it.[image: Pipe]

The pipe was uncovered - I vacuumed about 5 inches of dirt out and revealed a valve at the bottom with a square top. **Is this my main water shutoff valve?**

Relevant Info:

- Single story home (Could not find a shutoff valve in the crawlspace)
- Mountain Desert Climate
- Late 70's construction
- Diagram
  [image]

Comment: Turn the valve, will either turn off your water or open the secret missile silo.

Comment: Ya, livestream that :-)

Comment: Do you see a pipe entering the crawl space near where your blue dot is?  And branching out from there to the kitchen and bathrooms?   If there is no master valve in the crawl space it's quite likely that is what you have there ... but obviously an easy test would be the one suggested above.

Comment: There is a pipe entering the crawlspace near the dot, coming up from the ground at about a 45 degree angle. Looking for the correct tool to turn the valve now

Comment: Probably your water shut off - does it look like this?  https://www.plumbersstock.com/vmsw34-plain-pattern-34in-stop-waste-valve-lead-free-mueller.html

Comment: I think you need to take photos of side views. The one provided looks like a trumpet but a valve.